# How to prove a+c=b+d

Tags: geometry

[image: quadrilateral ABCD]

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral. Let $A′$ be the midpoint of $AB$, $B′$ the mid-point of $BC$, $C′$ the mid-point of $CD$ and $D′$ the mid-point of $AD$. Draw the lines $A′C′$ and $B′D′$ and let $a, b, c, d$ be the areas of the four minor quadrilaterals as shown in the figure. Prove that $a + c = b + d$.

I’ve realised that $a$ and $b$ have one of the same bases, but the other base is different. I think it has something to with $b$ sharing a base with $c$, and vice versa with $a$ and $d$.

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Hint: Let $M$ be the intersection of $A′C′$ and $B′D′$. Are there any relations between the area of pair of triangles on each side (e.g. $\triangle AA′M$, $\triangle A′BM$ on side $AB$)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint:

In this figure there are some triangles of same color that have the same area.
 Can you see why?